# image upload to amazon s3, need to be binary?

Tags: amazon-s3, binary, image-uploading

i have never used image upload before, don't really understand the mechanism .

Trying to upload image from backend, to amazon s3 buckets. does the image have to be converted to binary in this case?

the following code is what i got from amazon tutorial (can't find a good document&tutorial of how to use their api..)

what i need to add on the code to upload image ?

var params = {Bucket:bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: "?"};

s3.putObject(params, function(err,data){

if(err)
    console.log(err)
  else
    console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's alternative such as readasurl, to convert the image into a string, when the image is small. so.. no need to even use Amazon S3, which is so complicated...